# SEVERE: Servlet in web application threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException but .class is in the path

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat7

I am trying to run my program on Apache TomCat7 server but I got the following exception:

```
 SEVERE: Servlet [ConfigServlet] in web application [/asdf] threw load() exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.x.y.z.servlet.MainConfigServlet
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1858)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1701)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:486)
at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:113)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1146)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1085)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5610)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1572)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1562)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However when I checked target, I have found MainConfigServlet.class in .war file. there is no problem with deployment Assembly, Java Build Path etc. But still i cannot find the exact problem here.